# How do I escape content that might include a quotation mark?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to capture my search terms and pass them to a JavaScript variable, but I don't know how to handle quotes that might come through.

Here's what I have currently:

```
var searchTerms = "<!--#echo var="terms"-->";
var pattern = / /g;
newSearchTerms = searchTerms.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
var searchStr=newSearchTerms.replace(pattern,"_");
```

I'm concerned that should "terms" contain double quotes (or an apostrophy if I use single quotes in the JS) then my function will fail.

How do I escape the string before it gets into script?

Thanks,
Steve

---

Edit/answer: I ended up doing this by moving this to an external script that captured and parsed the querystring rather than echoing it in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

If `terms` contains quotation marks, by the time you have done `var searchTerms = "<!--#echo var="terms"-->";` it is already too late to replace any quotation marks, your JavaScript will be invalid. For example, if `terms` contains **These are the "terms"** your JavaScript would appear as follows (and produce a syntax error in the browser):

```
var searchTerms = "These are the "terms"";
```

If you are sure `terms` only contains double-quotes, you could do:

`var searchTerms = '<!--#echo var="terms"-->';`

If it could contain both single-quotes and double-quotes, you need to sanitize the output on the server using a server-side technology more sophisticated than `<!--#echo var="..."-->`.

Comment: Alternatively, I think you can set a variable to '"' in JavaScript.  Example:
     var DoubleQuotes = '"'
     var searchTerms = "<!--#echo var=" + DoubleQuotes + "terms" + DoubleQuotes + "-->";
This is useful when Obfuscating.

Comment: I don't think the server will process that statement as shown. I could be mistaken though.

Comment: @Dalin - I can't imagine the server being able to deal with that, but I'm interested in the idea that you can set DoubleQuotes. Could I read that to mean that I could do:
    DoubleQuotes = '"';
    var searchTerms = DoubleQuotes + <!--#echo var="terms"--> + DoubleQuotes;

Comment: DQ = '"'; var searchTerms = DQ + <!--#echo var="terms"--> + DQ; won't work. Given the same string above, you'd end up with var searchTerms = '"' + These are the "terms" + '"'; The result of the #echo isn't valid JavaScript, you'd still get a client-side syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

From your code it looks like you're using Apache SSI includes.  The `echo` SSI has an attribute called `encoding` which wil let you specify url-style encoding.  You can encode quotes this way and simply unencode in Javascript with `unescape()`

Try this:

```
var terms = "<!--#echo encoding="url" var="terms"-->";
terms = unescape(terms)
```

Comment: Sorry Triptych but that's not working on my set up of SSI, though I think I'm going to have to go down that path (unless I can get some more mileage out of Dalin's comment)

Comment: note that order is important; the "encoding" attribute MUST come before the "var" attribute.

Comment: yeah - I copied it verbatim. Our server's got minimal stuff turned on.

Answer (score 1):

i would add a javascript to the onchange event for the search textbox. capture the keystroke and ignore the quotes and any other special characters that might be entered. if the input is coming from the server side, then sanitize it before sending it to your script.